# Conectando Banco de Dados MYSQL com PHP e Phonegap

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, apache-cordova

Estou criando um app em *HTML*, *CSS* e *JS* com *Cordova*. E gostaria de saber como eu faço a conexão dele com um Banco de Dados de um server... No caso eu quero pegar as informações dele e passar pro app.

Comment: Tem que trabalhar com API, criar uma api em PHP ou outra linguagem e fazer chamadas via Ajax para a mesma

Answer (score -1):

Eu tenho um app que trabalha desta forma. O que vc precisa fazer é conectar o php ao mysql e todas as operações de update, select, insert fazer no php.
Toda vez que precisar fazer alguma operação, vc pode usar um ajax e apontar para as urls onde estão seu arquivos php.

Comment: E como faço isso? Tem algum tutorial?